# WordPress и TinyMCE редактор - удалить стили при вставке таблицы

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, редактор

На WordPress стоит дефолтный редактор TinyMCE.

Возникла задача добавить кнопку вставки таблицы.

Есть плагины, например:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mce-table-buttons/

и разные способы:

https://webistore.ru/cms/wordpress/kak-vstavit-knopku-tablicu-v-visualniy-redactor-wordpress-bez-plaginov/

По сути, просто расширяют функционал редактора TinyMCE, добавляя опцию, которая в нём и есть, только не по дефолту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но там проблема. Если мы вставляем таблицу по этой кнопке, то в html дописываются ненужные стили, свойства:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Которые приходятся потом удалять. Задача упростить, а, наоборот, приходится тратить время.

Это сам редактор чудит, или на WordPress так?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что придумать? Нужна просто кнопка - выбрал количество столбцов и ячеек, вставил код.

Comment: а почему не перейти на новый редактор WP? В нём весь необходимый набор элементов есть уже из коробки

Comment: Пользоваться Gutenberg'ом или классическим редактором, это вечные холивары)
В данном случае  — это опять лишние действия. В Classic открыли редактор, вставили таблицу по кнопке, нажали опубликовать. Проблема лишь в стилях.
Если брать Gutenberg, там столько возни с блоками будет. Зачем это надо для обычной задачи? Когда нужно много функционала, оно и понятно. А так, только потеря времени и ничем не лучше.

Comment: Я не слежу за холиварами, просто было любопытно. После перехода на Gutenberg у меня решилось столько геморроя с редакторскими задачами, что даже не предполагала что кому-то он приносит проблемы)

Comment: OMG, не понимать, зачем нужен Gutenberg через 3 года после его запуска...

Comment: Кто не понимать? Я? Повторюсь, если мне нужно будет множество функционала, гибкость, работа с блоками или еще что, то я конечно будут им пользоваться)
В данном случае не подходит. На вставку таблицы и создание поста я трачу буквально пару кликов и какие-то секунды, а с Gutenbergom я сколько действий должен сделать и сколько времени это займет? А если сотни постов, тысячи? Разница будет измеряться часами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Чтобы удалялись ненужные стили таблиц, необходимо в functions.php темы добавить следующий код:

```
function tinymce_fix_table_styles() {   
  echo '<script>jQuery(function($){
    if (typeof tinymce !== "undefined") {
      tinymce.overrideDefaults({
        table_default_attributes:{},
        table_default_styles:{}
      });
    }
  });</script>';
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'tinymce_fix_table_styles');
```

Если не сработало, есть еще такой вариант (использовать отдельно):

```
function mce_settings( $settings ) {
    $settings['table_default_styles'] = false;
    $settings['table_default_attributes'] = false;
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_settings' );
```